# Callback function - how to know what the argument content is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

[image]

See attached picture from React, index.js file. I am retrieving data from youtube API. However, I do not understand how the code understands what "data" is, as this was never defined earlier in my code.

Is it something with the structure, that always puts the data from the search, in whatever I have as an argument, in a next function?

The code works, "data" contains the data retrieved from the API search. I just dont understand how the search content, automatically ends up in "data" (or whatever I name the argument).

Can anyone explain this - thanks!

Comment: It is whatever the api returns..... It does it thing and calls your callback with whatever it does. No different that you calling a function and passing an argument. `function foo(data) {}; foo(12345);`

Comment: You're passing in a callback function - in this case, an anonymous function. That uses `data` as a formal parameter - but as with all function parameters, it doesn't actually matter what it's called. (Except for readability, which is obviously quite important.) So `data` will be whatever is actually passed into the callback when it's called. You'll have to look at the documentation for `YTSearch` to see how it will be called, and what the argument represents.

Answer (score 0):

`YTSearch` is probably library code that makes a request to a remote server, parses a JSON response and passes it into the callback with `data` as the first argument. If you're curious, you can add a [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement before the `YTSearch` call and step into the function to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

the last function here is a callback function to the YTSearch. YTSearch is a react library for including youtube videos. All you have to do is call YTSearch(), the search takes an argument in the form of an object including your API key and the search term. The callback function will be used to return the results and in the case below, it can be used to set the state.
So basically the callback function is called by YTSearch method and pass it results through it. data is just a parameter and you can name it anything you want.

A simple example here:

```
function callback (data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function YTSearch(obj,callback) {
  //calculates data internally based on obj - API key and searchString
  //finally passes it through the callback function
  callback(data);
}

YTSearch({key:'API_KEY',term:'surfboards'},callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine below is the `YTSearch` method you're calling (simplified). The second argument `callback` accepts a function which is called at the end of `YTSearch`.

The response `fromDatabase` is passed as the first argument to this `callback` function.

When you call `YTSearch` and pass your own function as the second argument you receive the data in your first argument (which you can name  `data`, `response` or anything else).

```
function YTSearch(options, callback) {
     // query database for some data based on "options"
     const fromDatabase = {name: 'Tom', age: 29};
     callback(fromDatabase);
}

YTSearch({name: 'tom'}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // {name: 'Tom', age: 29}
});
```